# Sphinx HTML Python documentation hangs in web browser

Tags: python, themes, python-sphinx

Using a particularly fancy theme, the Sphinx-generated HTML webpages hang when loading in google chrome. Anyone familiar with this problem or have general advice for debugging it?

I downloaded the theme from:

https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org

I zip the folder "sphinx_rtd_theme" and reference it from a "_themes" folder according to:

[http://www.westga.edu/~drocco/sphinx/themes.html](http://www.westga.edu/%7Edrocco/sphinx/themes.html)

Any code can be used to cause this same problem I'm having. For instance, borrowing snippets from here will do:

http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html

`make html` command returns absolutely no warnings and publishes the HTML perfectly. However, upon clicking "index.html" it locks up. Clicking stop in the web browser will end the hang and the web page appears to have loaded perfectly.

I've managed to apply several dozen different Sphinx themes successfully to my project and its only this one I've had issues with so I may just revert to another one unless its a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This line](https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/master/sphinx_rtd_theme/layout.html#L88) seems to be the problem:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

The link to modernizr is broken and browser kinda hangs on it. Bug the dev about it?

Comment: I am not very keen on web scripting so if you have any insight on what this line is trying to accomplish it is much appreciated. I just went ahead and deleted it and everything works fine. Ill report the concern to them - thanks!

Comment: they now corrected the bug. that line now reads: `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>`